# error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7 when compile the flutter app

Tags: flutter

Recently I upgrade the flutter dependencies `flutter_secure_storage` to new version 5.0.0. Today When I compile the flutter(2.5.x) project, shows error like this:

```
/Users/dolphin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/it_nomads/fluttersecurestorage/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.java:250: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
            handler.post(() -> methodResult.success(result));
                            ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
/Users/dolphin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/it_nomads/fluttersecurestorage/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.java:260: error: method references are not supported in -source 7
            handler.post(methodResult::notImplemented);
                                       ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

why shows error like this? what should I do to fix this problem? what should I do to specify the java version in flutter project?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a new `flutter_secure_storage` version issue, you should wait for the next version to fix. More information about this issue:https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/330 to avoid this problem, tried to downgrade the `flutter_secure_storage` version to 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Clear .pub-cache using
`rm -r ~/.pub-cache` in terminal.

Please note this will delete .pub-cache folder from your computer

Run `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and then `flutter run`. It should work as expected.

Comment: I tried what you said but still did not fix this problem.@Kaushik Chandru